# Found 2 versions of .jar after installing the facebook api on eclipce. in my new app

Tags: android, facebook, eclipse, api, jar

Eclipse Console message :

```
Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list
but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
Versions found are:
Path: /Users/itaiirdam/Documents/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2.b/facebook/libs/android-support-v4.jar
Length: 349252
SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
Path: /Users/itaiirdam/Documents/workspace1/CTPuppy/libs/android-support-v4.jar
Length: 385677
SHA-1: b9c504522d97f64025c387493d3989e52bc617bd
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
Versions found are:
Path: /Users/itaiirdam/Documents/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2.b/facebook/libs/android-support-v4.jar
Length: 349252
SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
Path: /Users/itaiirdam/Documents/workspace1/CTPuppy/libs/android-support-v4.jar
Length: 385677
SHA-1: b9c504522d97f64025c387493d3989e52bc617bd
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Answer (score 9):

It's because the third party api has the support library in it. The same support library might also be contained in your project. `Delete the common support library from your project's libs.` This should fix your problem and let me know the result.